# Table element isn't stretching across 100%

Tags: html, css, forum

I have been attempting to get an element to stretch across the entire length of a table, the issue has been that a certain space is always left at the very edge of this element.

So I've been trying to stretch the element that handles 'recent posts' all the way across to the edge, and I had been messing with it for several hours attempting to change the display and change how it was formatted.

**NOTE**: Due to the mess on the website in question I've taken the time to wrap up everything that was an issue and the solution into a single JSFiddle... That should make it easier for anyone to understand the solution.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zm7bpr8p/2/

```
<table width="1000" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Test1</th>
<th>Test2</th>
<th>HEAD1</th>
<th>HEAD2</th>
<th>Comments</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>Test1</td>
<td>Test2</td>
<td class="DR1">DISABLED</td>
<td class="DR2">DISABLED2</td>
<td>Comments</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, I'll add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problems with the columns of your table.

Your first row have 5 cells but others only have 3 (".threads" and ".posts" are not visible).

Hide these two cells also in your th and problem solved.

Transform:

```
td.threads, td.posts {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

To:

```
td.threads, td.posts, th.threads, th.posts {
    display: none;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Those are already set as 'display:none' which would mean that they have no effect on the actual format of the content.. If I set them as 'visibility:hidden' then they would still affect the content and I'd be left with a gap in between the forum and the recent.

Comment: At least as far as I can see they have no effect on the actual display, and each of these rows have 5 columns, three are visible, and two are display:none.... I unfortunately have no way to completely remove them due to Proboards restriction.

Comment: Tables must be consistent, you can not have a row with 5 cells and the following with 3. Your thead have 5 cells and others rows only have 3.

Comment: The thead is the first row of each table which has no content.

Comment: I understand this, but at least from what I can see it has three cells in each of them, it is technically five but two of them are 'display:none' which would have no bearing on the actual look of the table.

Comment: Aha! Now I see what you were talking about, my apologies... Amusingly enough I had looked for exactly that.

Comment: I imagine an answer like this already exists on the forum, but I will make an 'example' code real quick to show the issue and show the correction in effect.

Comment: Easy fix now that those are removed... Just makes me feel quite stupid that I missed that for hours, especially considering how long I've been programming. x.x But I guess it just takes a second perspective to find some of those little things, so once again.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your "thread" of your table, there are still five columns with "threads" and "posts" still visible. Seems you have miss adding this CSS style.

```
/*Add this CSS style*/

.list >thead .threads, .list >thead .posts {
   display: none;
}
```

or you can just hide all "threads" and "posts" column.

```
/*Add this CSS style*/
.list .threads, .list .posts {
   display: none;
}
```

hope this can help you ;)

Comment: Exact solution I just checked as the answer, really quite unfortunate that I hadn't noticed that after hours... Found myself looking way deeper than I needed to, so I thank you for your assistance along with Gabriel.

Comment: no thanks. Glad that you have solved your problem. :)